# Redis pubsub in play

Tags: scala, playframework, redis, playframework-2.0, actor

I'm trying to have a redis client within my play application which will subscribe for updates from redis.
There isn't much on it on the net, I'm using this as reference:
https://github.com/pvillega/play21-redis-pubsub/blob/master/app/controllers/Application.scala

From what I understand it's much easier to accomplish this with scala than java, but I have no scala skills, and so I'm trying to understand things..
What I want is a singleton object through which I will be able to publish and get updates (using subscribers) from the entire application.

Here's what I came up with:

```
object Redis extends Actor {
    val channel = "myChannel"
    val plugin = Play.application.plugin(classOf[RedisPlugin]).get
    val pool = plugin.sedisPool
    val listener = new PubSubListener()
    val subscribers = mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[Subscriber]

    Future {
        pool.withJedisClient { client =>
            client.subscribe(listener, channel)
        }
    }(Contexts.redisExecutionContext)

    def receive = {
        case _ => Logger.error("received unknown message")
    }

    def onMessage(message: String): Unit = {
        Logger.debug("MESSAGE FROM REDIS: " + message)

        Redis.subscribers.synchronized {
            for (subscriber <- Redis.subscribers) subscriber.receive(message)
        }
    }

    def addSubscriber(subscriber: Subscriber): Unit = {
        this.subscribers.synchronized {
            this.subscribers += subscriber
        }
    }
}

object Contexts {
    implicit val redisExecutionContext: ExecutionContext = Akka.system.dispatchers.lookup("akka.actor.redis-pubsub-context")
}

trait Subscriber {
    def receive(message: String): Unit
}

case class PubSubListener() extends JedisPubSub {
    def onMessage(channel: String, message: String): Unit = {
        Logger.debug("MESSAGE FROM REDIS: " + message)
        Redis.onMessage(message)
    }

    ...
}
```

This code does not work, it compiles and does not break in runtime, but it pretty much does nothing..
What it should do is to register for redis updates and that's it.

What am I missing (probably a lot!)?
Thanks!

Comment: I prefer using this one: https://github.com/njin-fr/play2-rediscala and it well works easily.

Comment: We reviewed using Redis pub/sub in a play application but ended up using Akka Event Bus - it's pretty simple and works nicely. Have a look at http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/event-bus.html.

Comment: Thanks! We ended up implementing it on another server (which isn't using play) since too much time was spent on making it work

Answer (score 3):

There is a sample application (Scalable chat application with Play and WebSockets) which uses Redis Pub/Sub and the Play Framework 2.x in Java. The Redis client used is Jedis (Java). There are even instructions to directly deploy the application to Heroku.

If you want to run the application locally, install Redis, run the redis server and update the Redis configuration in conf/application.conf

```
#Redis configuration
redis.uri="http://localhost:6379"
```

Link to the tutorial of the sample application - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/play-java-websockets-advanced

Link to the github repository - https://github.com/heroku-examples/play-websockets-chat-sample

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately we haven't stayed with play and so I can't check your answer. +1 for what seems to be a detailed answer